# SQL using CASE in SELECT with GROUP BY. Need CASE-value but get row-value

Tags: sql, db2, case, where-clause

so basicially there is 1 question and 1 problem:

**1. question** - when I have like 100 columns in a table(and no key or uindex is set) and I want to join or subselect that table with itself, do I really have to write out every column name?

**2. problem** - the example below shows the 1. question and my actual SQL-statement problem

Example:

```
A.FIELD1,
(SELECT CASE WHEN B.FIELD2 = 1 THEN B.FIELD3 ELSE null FROM TABLE B WHERE A.* = B.*) AS CASEFIELD1
(SELECT CASE WHEN B.FIELD2 = 2 THEN B.FIELD4 ELSE null FROM TABLE B WHERE A.* = B.*) AS CASEFIELD2
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY A.FIELD1
```

The story is: if I don't put the CASE into its own select statement then I have to put the actual rowname into the GROUP BY and the GROUP BY doesn't group the NULL-value from the CASE but the actual value from the row. And because of that I would have to either join or subselect with all columns, since there is no key and no uindex, or somehow find another solution.

DBServer is DB2.

So now to describing it just with words and no SQL:
I have "order items" which can be divided into "ZD" and "EK" (1 = ZD, 2 = EK) and can be grouped by "distributor". Even though "order items" can have one of two different "departements"(ZD, EK), the  fields/rows for "ZD" and "EK" are always both filled. I need the grouping to consider the "departement" and only if the designated "departement" (ZD or EK) is changing, then I want a new group to be created.

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN TABLE.DEPARTEMENT = 1 THEN TABLE.ZD ELSE null END) AS ZD,
(CASE WHEN TABLE.DEPARTEMENT = 2 THEN TABLE.EK ELSE null END) AS EK,
TABLE.DISTRIBUTOR,
sum(TABLE.SOMETHING) AS SOMETHING,
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY
ZD
EK
TABLE.DISTRIBUTOR
TABLE.DEPARTEMENT
```

This here worked in the SELECT and ZD, EK in the GROUP BY. Only problem was, even if EK was not the designated DEPARTEMENT, it still opened a new group if it changed, because he was using the real EK value and not the NULL from the CASE, as I was already explaining up top.

Comment: Do you mean checking the value of each column of table A to the column  in table b with the same column name, and all columns must match?  Or do you mean some other type of logic?

Comment: Exactly, but that is just the question though and not the real problem, which I will try to further/better explain in near time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And here ladies and gentleman is the solution to the problem:

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN TABLE.DEPARTEMENT = 1 THEN TABLE.ZD ELSE null END) AS ZD,
(CASE WHEN TABLE.DEPARTEMENT = 2 THEN TABLE.EK ELSE null END) AS EK,
TABLE.DISTRIBUTOR,
sum(TABLE.SOMETHING) AS SOMETHING,
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY
(CASE WHEN TABLE.DEPARTEMENT = 1 THEN TABLE.ZD ELSE null END),
(CASE WHEN TABLE.DEPARTEMENT = 2 THEN TABLE.EK ELSE null END),
TABLE.DISTRIBUTOR,
TABLE.DEPARTEMENT
```

@t-clausen.dk: Thank you!

@others: ...

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a wildcard equality test.
I am not sure why you would group by field1, that would seem impossible in your example. I tried to fit it into your question:

```
SELECT FIELD1,
CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 1 THEN FIELD3 END AS CASEFIELD1,
CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 2 THEN FIELD4 END AS CASEFIELD2
FROM 
(
 SELECT * FROM A
 INTERSECT
 SELECT * FROM B
) C
UNION -- results in a distinct
SELECT
A.FIELD1,
null,
null
FROM 
(
 SELECT * FROM A
 EXCEPT
 SELECT * FROM B
) C
```

This will fail for datatypes that are not comparable

Comment: This is a good answer to my question, but it is sad though that it is only possible in such a clutterd manner. Now only the problem needs to be solved.

Comment: @Khazar yes it is very complex. But just wanted to demonstrate that it was possible

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no wildcard equality test. You'd have to list every field you want tested individually. If you don't want to test each individual field, you could use a hack such as concatenating all the fields, e.g.

```
WHERE (a.foo + a.bar + a.baz) = (b.foo + b.bar + b.az)
```

but either way, you're listing all of the fields.

Comment: "+" is not the concatenation operator, your example will fail if there is a non-numeric column. Even if you use the proper concatenation, it won't work correctly in many cases. For example `'a' || null || 'c'` and `'a' || 'b' || null` will both return NULL, while the intent obviously would be to treat these combinations as different. On the other hand, one NULL value is not equal to another NULL value, so `'a' || null || 'c'` and `'a' || null || 'c'` will not be equal either, though intent in this case would be to treat them as equal.

Comment: Please go yell at the SQL standards body and tell them to settle on a standard operator, then...

Comment: Please go yell at whoever you want yourself. The ANSI SQL standard clearly specifies the double vertical bar as the concatenation operator.

Comment: @MarcB If a question is tagged for a particular DBMS, then don't you think the answer should be appropriate for that environment? A mySQL answer might be inappropriate under SQL Server.  A T-SQL answer may be inappropriate under DB2.  Personally, if suggesting an answer for a system I am unfamiliar with, I try to check the appropriate reference if I have time.  And I generally include a caveat that my experience is primarily on ___.  This gives readers a heads up to    be a bit more cautious in taking my answer verbatim, to double check the details, and hopefully be more lenient in a critique.

Answer (score 1):

I might tend to solve it something like this

```
WITH q as
(SELECT
       Department
     , (CASE WHEN DEPARTEMENT = 1 THEN ZD
             WHEN DEPARTEMENT = 2 THEN EK
                                  ELSE null 
        END) AS GRP
     , DISTRIBUTOR
     , SOMETHING 
   FROM mytable
)
SELECT 
       Department
     , Grp
     , Distributor

     , sum(SOMETHING) AS SumTHING
  FROM q
GROUP BY
       DEPARTEMENT 
     , GRP
     , DISTRIBUTOR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find all rows in TableA that match in TableB, how about INTERSECT or INTERSECT DISTINCT?

```
select * from A
 INTERSECT DISTINCT
select * from B
```

However, if you only want rows from A where the entire row matches the values in a row from B, then why does your sample code take some values from A and others from B?  If the row matches on all columns, then that would seem pointless.  (Perhaps your question could be explained a bit more fully?)

Comment: The problem is with the GROUP BY and the CASE. I need the value that comes from the CASE but I can't use an alias(which I need to do because I don't want to group FIELD3, FIELD4 and their unfiltered values) unless I use a subselect. So yes the subselect is normally pointless, but not in this case.

Comment: Please explain the requirement(s) in english, including (but not limited to) what you need to do with the CASE logic, and the matching logic.  Leave the SQL out for now.  We can provide that, once we clearly and unambiguously understand exactly what needs to be done,

Comment: @t-clausen Sorry, don't know why I didn't see your answer while giving mine.

Comment: Is the explanation understandable, in the way I wrote it?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. It seems you are past the point of asking about a.*=b.*, correct? It looks like your SQL is now approaching a good solution, eh? Good job. I'll add how I would do this soon.

Comment: Sorry to say this but this SQL code at the bottom is the code I had before the top one. ;) The top one was an attempt to get out of the problem of GROUP BY using the row-value and not the CASE-value.